# Can you include speech in a Readied Action?

Tags: dnd-5e, readied-action

During a readied action, can a character perform speech? For example:

Can I speak while enacting my readied action? Such as if my readied action is to stab someone and yell "cowabunga!" when they walk by. Per this [question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/101430/can-i-say-something-to-an-ally-when-its-not-my-turn-and-we-are-both-in-combat/101431#101431) it seems you can't normally speak outside of your turn.

Comment: Also, Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) if you haven't already, and check out the [help center](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help) for more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: @NautArch Ah ok, I was thinking of it as one big question of what can I do during a readied action besides move/action. I think I understand the bonus action/reaction well enough, so I'll just copy the first question into it's own question.

Comment: You may want to have this just include speech. [This question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/122998/do-you-get-your-free-interaction-during-a-readied-action) covers the free interaction/ready action.

Comment: I removed the section on free interactions since my earlier comment shows that one is a dupe. If you disagree, let us know!

Comment: You are correct, I was unable to find that question during my previous searches. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While the post you reference has an answer, saying that you could speak using your reaction, the **RAW** say nothing about being able to speak out of turn, while performing a separate readied action. However, the [SRD](http://www.5esrd.com/gamemastering/combat/#Other_Activity_on_Your_Turn) states:

> You can communicate however you are able, through brief utterances and gestures, as you take your turn.

In **RAW** if and only if your reaction occurs on your turn could you speak in character and perform an action, but this seems to be a stiff interpretation of the **RAI**. It seems likely that because your character is acting in that moment that they could also speak a short phrase in whatever time that specific reaction gives them. As a DM in a situation where intra-party communication was critical 1 or 2 words seems perfectly reasonable for a reaction.

Narratively, if your character was waiting at a corner to strike the first person they saw coming around it, they would not be magically gagged while attacking.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, as you mention the question I linked suggested using your reaction to speak outside your turn, but in this case since you're using your reaction for your readied action I wasn't sure that was applicable. I feel a reasonable DM would allow it, but I guess I was hoping there were official rules/rulings somewhere.

Comment: Yeah I looked and I had a feeling the 5e official rulings for talking in character and at the table were as small as I thought. It basically provides a framework so everyone can say what they want to do on their turn and that's it, to keep from being talked over.

Comment: Per [this meta](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7528/please-avoid-using-the-rai-acronym-or-use-it-carefully-be-clear-in-context), you should clarify what you mean by "RAI" or expand the acronym to write out what it's referring to.