# Does Readied movement count as "your move"?

Tags: dnd-5e, movement, readied-action

The [Ready action](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#Ready) states:

> Then, you choose the action you will take in response to that trigger, or you choose to **move up to your speed** in response to it...

However there are several times where the rules use the phrase "your move" and I am unsure how this interacts with the Ready action. Some examples are provided below (All emphasis is mine):

And the rules on ["Mounting and Dismounting"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#MountingandDismounting) state:

> Once **during your move**, you can mount a creature that is within 5 feet of you or dismount.

Under ["Other Activity On Your Turn"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#OtherActivityonYourTurn) it states:

> Your turn can include a variety of flourishes that require neither your action nor **your move**.

From ["Moving Around Other Creatures"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#MovingAroundOtherCreatures)

> Whether a creature is a friend or an enemy, you can’t willingly end **your move** in its space.

And then under the ["Breaking Up Your Move"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#UsingDifferentSpeeds) section:

> If you have more than one speed, such as your walking speed and a flying speed, you can switch back and forth between your speeds **during your move**.

My main question is the title "Does Readied movement count as 'your move'?" Another way to phrase this could be as follows:

**Some of the things listed above can only be done "during your move". Can you do them during Readied movement?**

Comment: Related: [What are the basic limitations for using a Reaction to move?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/124103/48793)

Comment: Related: [Do you get your free interaction during a readied action?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/122998)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Yes. Readied or not, movement is movement.

The definition of "movement" in the rules doesn't change based on whether it's done on your turn or someone else's. The rules don't say that if you move on your turn, it's considered "your move", and that it's called something else if you move on someone else's turn. It's just that you don't normally have a pool of movement to use outside your turn unless you take the Ready action.

From the ["Movement and Position"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#MovementandPosition) section:

> On your turn, you can move a distance up to your speed. You can use as much or as little of your speed as you like on your turn, following the rules here.

The [Ready](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#Ready) action says (emphasis mine):

> Sometimes you want to get the jump on a foe or wait for a particular circumstance before you act. To do so, you can take the Ready action on your turn, which lets you act using your reaction before the start of your next turn.
>
> First, you decide what perceivable circumstance will trigger your reaction. Then, you choose the action you will take in response to that trigger, or **you choose to move up to your speed in response to it**. Examples include "If the cultist steps on the trapdoor, I'll pull the lever that opens it," and **"If the goblin steps next to me, I move away."**

In addition, consider that things like the rules on [difficult terrain](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#DifficultTerrain) state:

> Every foot of **movement** in difficult terrain costs 1 extra foot.

If the term "your move" or "your movement" only applied to your turn, then difficult terrain would somehow impede regular movement on your turn but not impede readied movement. This is clearly illogical.

### ...But features related to your move might separately restrict timing

Some of the things dependent on your movement may also specify whose turn that movement must be on. For instance, the ["Other Activity on Your Turn"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#OtherActivityonYourTurn) section that you quoted specifies, in addition to the name of the section (emphasis mine):

> **Your turn** can include a variety of flourishes that require neither your action nor your move.

The options specified in this section relate to what can be done during your turn. Even if you want to do some other activity as part of your move (e.g. interacting with one object or feature of the environment), you can only do it as part of your own turn, not as part of your readied movement. For more details, see:

- [Do you get your free interaction during a readied action?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/122998/do-you-get-your-free-interaction-during-a-readied-action)
- [Can you include speech in a Readied Action?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/147109/can-you-include-speech-in-a-readied-action)

Naturally, DMs may choose to allow these as part of readied actions at their discretion, but the rules clearly delineate them as "other activity on your turn".

Answer (score -3):

## Some of them.

You could declare that you plan to mount a horse as a reaction.

The other activities on your turn refers to things like talking or gesturing, e.g. warning an ally of a threat or pointing which way a monster fled. Generally speaking, a DM will let you do things like this for free outside of your turn, but by the rules they are supposed to be done during your turn. Either way, these activities don't require movement.

Regardless of whether it is your turn or a readied action, you can't deliberately end your movement in another creature's space.

If you are using a readied action to move, you can walk, fly, climb or burrow, provided you have the ability to do so.

Regardless. Using readied movement in combat has the same rules as regular movement. These rules are covered here. You can't break the movement rules just because you are using a readied movement.

Comment: I'm unsure how this answers whether Readied movement counts as "your move". What is your evidence that these terms are equivalent?