# Ready Action Multiple Attacks

Tags: dnd-5e, readied-action

How many attacks do I get with a ready action?

I normally get two attacks in an action, an action surge attack(when I use an action surge), and a bonus action attack. If I ready an attack so that it triggers when an enemy appears, how many attacks do I get?

I take it the action surge and bonus action can't be readied, but since the readied action is now a reaction, do I still get my two attacks?

Comment: *If* you're talking about D&D5e, is it the class feature Extra Attack that you're talking about? If so, see also this question: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/91374/23970